# How to seperate CSV values with in a cell in pyspark dataframe to new columns and their values respectively

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

The current spark data frame has CSV values in cell level of one column, I trying to explode it to new columns. The example dataframe

```
    a_id                                    features
1   2020     "a","b","c","d","constant1","1","0.1","aa"
2   2021     "a","b","c","d","constant2","1","0.2","ab"
3   2022     "a","b","c","d","constant3","1","0.3","ac","a","b","c","d","constant3","1.1","3.3","acx"
4   2023     "a","b","c","d","constant4","1","0.4","ad"
5   2024     "a","b","c","d","constant5","1","0.5","ae","a","b","c","d","constant5","1.2","6.3","xwy","a","b","c","d","constant5","2.2","8.3","bunr"
6   2025     "a","b","c","d","constant6","1","0.6","af"
```

The features column has multiple csv values, and in it (a, b, c, d) act as header and they get repeated in some cells (in row 3 and 5), I want to extract only one header and its respective values. The output of the expected dataframe is as shown

**Output spark dataframe**

```
    a_id       a        d
1   2020   constant1   ["aa"]
2   2021   constant2   ["ab"]
3   2022   constant3   ["ac","acx"]
4   2023   constant4   ["ad"]
5   2024   constant5   ["ae","xwy","bunr"]
6   2025   constant6   ["af"]
```

As shown, I would like to extract only a and d headers as new columns, where a is constant and d has multiple values, where its values made as list.

Please help how to convert this in pysaprk. The above dataframe is streaming dataframe in real time.

Comment: you could do a user defined function that will parse the row (one for each column), first function fills the "a" column by checking for "constant" string, second function fills "d" column by concatenating each %7 index of the string split by ","

Comment: thanks, But if u can show how to the "d" in code, I would appreciate that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using only Pyspark/Spark SQL functions:

- remove the headers from the string
- extract the substrings using [regexp_extract_all](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/sql/index.html#regexp_extract_all), breaking the string into substrings after each fourth `,`
- `explode` the result and remove empty lines
- `split` the result again. Now each csv value is an element of an array
- create columns `a` and `d` from the first and fourth element of the array
- group by `a_id`

```scala
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

header='"a","b","c","d",'
num_headers = header.count(",")

df.withColumn("features", F.expr(f"replace(features, '{header}')")) \
  .withColumn("features", F.expr(f"regexp_extract_all(features, '(([^,]*,?)\\{{{num_headers}}})')")) \
  .withColumn("features", F.explode("features"))\
  .filter("not features =''") \
  .withColumn("features", F.split("features", ",")) \
  .withColumn("a", F.expr("features[0]")) \
  .withColumn("d", F.expr("features[3]")) \
  .groupBy("a_id") \
  .agg(F.first("a").alias("a"), F.collect_list("d").alias("d")) \
  .show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+----+----------+---------------------+
|a_id|a         |d                    |
+----+----------+---------------------+
|2020|"constant"|["aa"]               |
|2022|"constant"|["ac", "acx"]        |
|2025|"constant"|["af"]               |
|2023|"constant"|["ad"]               |
|2021|"constant"|["ab"]               |
|2024|"constant"|["ae", "xwy", "bunr"]|
+----+----------+---------------------+
```