# Separate CSV values with in a cell in pyspark dataframe to new columns and their values

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

The current spark data frame has CSV values in cell level of one column, I trying to explode it to new columns. The example dataframe

```
    a_id                                    features
1   2020     "a","b","c","d","constant1","1","0.1","aa"
2   2021     "a","b","c","d","constant2","1","0.2","ab"
3   2022     "a","b","c","d","constant3","1","0.3","ac","constant3","1.1","3.3","acx"
4   2023     "a","b","c","d","constant4","1","0.4","ad"
5   2024     "a","b","c","d","constant5","1","0.5","ae","constant5","1.2","6.3","xwy","a","b","c","d","constant5","2.2","8.3","bunr"
6   2025     "a","b","c","d","constant6","1","0.6","af"
```

The features column has multiple csv values, and in it (a, b, c, d) act as header and they get repeated in some cells (in row 3 and 5), I want to extract only one header and its respective values. The output of the expected dataframe is as shown

The code used from the link before applying split function
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69454826/10360845)

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

header='"a","b","c","d",'
num_headers = header.count(",")

df.withColumn("features", F.expr(f"replace(features, '{header}')")) \
  .withColumn("features", F.expr(f"regexp_extract_all(features, '(([^,]*,?)\\{{{num_headers}}})')")) \
  .withColumn("features", F.explode("features"))\
  .filter("not features =''") \
  .withColumn("features", F.split("features", ",")) \
  .withColumn("a", F.expr("features[0]")) \
  .withColumn("d", F.expr("features[3]")) \
  .groupBy("a_id") \
  .agg(F.first("a").alias("a"), F.collect_list("d").alias("d")) \
  .show(truncate=False)
```

what is the way to code with out counting the number of headers as shown, What if there is a possibility of additional columns, I want to avoid the hard coding (Assigning headers to a variable). please give insight on this.

**Output spark dataframe**

```
    a_id       a        d
1   2020   constant1   ["aa"]
2   2021   constant2   ["ab"]
3   2022   constant3   ["ac","acx"]
4   2023   constant4   ["ad"]
5   2024   constant5   ["ae","xwy","bunr"]
6   2025   constant6   ["af"]
```

Please find the sample data I have added to google sheets here in the link [Sheet1 has Input Sheet2 has Output](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dsvp_VxPWF_r849zBRPnu8TSrVh7duvpGUOjJq4jLQA/edit?usp=sharing) for the reference. I hope this data helps

Comment: How can we infer from the data which part of the string are the headers and where the actual row data begins?

Comment: in the actual data, If I split data by (,) comma it gives me a new line char  "\n". Similarly we have \n character after the values respectively. Can I utilize \n as indicator.

Comment: It's pretty hard to make a reproducible sample with this kind of problem. Would you mind uploading a sample of the actual CSV file?

Comment: I have added the data to google sheets and uploaded the link to the question, Please check. @pltc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon a close observation, The list of values weren't split by rows i.e (using the delimiter `\n`) and this `\n` value was in one of the list elements between the ending value of a row and starting value of a new one (eg. `"\"pir\"\n\"608abc\""`). CSVs can be tricky but what was good about the sample was that the cell values were in `"`. As such, The desired results were achieved using the following steps to clean, order and eventually pivot the data into the desired format:

***NB.** I noted that there are no `a` and `d` headers in your sample dataset shared, so I will describe how you can do this for any desired column(s) in Step 10*

**Steps**

1. The list column `features` was joined into one string using `concat_ws` since each csv line was not easily discernable by row using the `\n`. These values were concatenated using the `|` delimiter.
2. With an entire string in `features`, the csv was split into rows using `split` by the `\n` character
3. The headers were extracted as the first element from this list. You stated that each row would have the headers and that they would be repeated. The repeated headers will be removed later, however this step is important to identify the headers.
4. The next step is to treat the data as rows and this was achieved using `posexplode`. This would split the list into rows  with values in `col` and also share the order or csv row number in `pos`. This was done in a `select`
5. The repeat headers were removed from the set of rows in `col` (using `F.col("headers") != F.col("col")`) and empty rows were removed also(`(F.length(F.col("col"))>0)`). This was easier since the `headers` were extracted earlier into another column named `headers`.
6. `pos` was renamed to `row_num` as this would inform us of which row in the csv we were working with
7. In another select, `posexplode` was used to get the cell/column values split from `col` into different rows as we intend to pivot on these. The headers were also `split` as we intend to treat it as a list going forth
8. The associated headers for each column in each row (i.e. cell value) was retrieved using the `pos` from the split cell values to index the list of headers as both header and cell value would share the same column number stored in `pos`
9. The `"` character was removed from the header and cell values
10. You may filter based on your desired columns (eg. filtering on `Number,car,car_name`) using `isin`. If this line/filter is removed, you will get all columns as seen in your shared google sheets
11. The data was grouped on `id` and `row_num`
12. A pivot was done on `header` to get each cell value into a column. The pivot value used was the `` max(`col`) `` which would return the old cell value for that respective column in that `id` and `row_num` group

**Initial data shared in google sheets**

| id | features |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [""Number"",""avg_ch"",""avg_port"",""ctn"",""acc"",""car"",""net"",""car_name"",""req_w"",""req_h"",""ooids"",""last"",""ivrInt"",""ivrFai"",""careInt"",""careFai"",""retlInt"",""retlFai"",""piTE"",""piTS"",""pasC"",""ss_i"",""ss_c"",""acc_cat"",""total1"",""total2"",""total3"",""total4"",""total5"",""total6"",""total7"",""total8"",""total9"",""total10"",""total11"",""total12"",""total13"",""total14"",""total15"",""total16"",""day1"",""day2"",""day3"",""day4"",""day5"",""day6"",""day7"",""day8"",""day9"",""day10"",""day11"",""day12"",""day13"",""day14"",""day15"",""day16"",""day17"",""total17"",""csm1"",""csm2"",""pir"\n"608abc"","""","""","""","""",""ZZZZ-TM"",""TM"",""RES"",""7"",""20"","""",""2431.3522631166666"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"","""","""",""OTHERS"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"\n"814abc"","""","""","""","""",""TRAC"",""OTHERS"",""TRAC"",""7"",""20"","""","""",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"","""","""",""OTHERS"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"\n"] |
| 2 | [""Number"",""avg_ch"",""avg_port"",""ctn"",""acc"",""car"",""net"",""car_name"",""req_w"",""req_h"",""ooids"",""last"",""ivrInt"",""ivrFai"",""careInt"",""careFai"",""retlInt"",""retlFai"",""piTE"",""piTS"",""pasC"",""ss_i"",""ss_c"",""acc_cat"",""total1"",""total2"",""total3"",""total4"",""total5"",""total6"",""total7"",""total8"",""total9"",""total10"",""total11"",""total12"",""total13"",""total14"",""total15"",""total16"",""day1"",""day2"",""day3"",""day4"",""day5"",""day6"",""day7"",""day8"",""day9"",""day10"",""day11"",""day12"",""day13"",""day14"",""day15"",""day16"",""day17"",""total17"",""csm1"",""csm2"",""pir"\n"608abc"","""","""","""","""",""ZZZZ-TM"",""TM"",""RES"",""7"",""20"","""",""2431.3514778000003"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"","""","""",""OTHERS"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"\n"814abc"","""","""","""","""",""TRAC"",""OTHERS"",""TRAC"",""7"",""20"","""","""",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"","""","""",""OTHERS"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"\n"] |
| 3 | [""Number"",""avg_ch"",""avg_port"",""ctn"",""acc"",""car"",""net"",""car_name"",""req_w"",""req_h"",""ooids"",""last"",""ivrInt"",""ivrFai"",""careInt"",""careFai"",""retlInt"",""retlFai"",""piTE"",""piTS"",""pasC"",""ss_i"",""ss_c"",""acc_cat"",""total1"",""total2"",""total3"",""total4"",""total5"",""total6"",""total7"",""total8"",""total9"",""total10"",""total11"",""total12"",""total13"",""total14"",""total15"",""total16"",""day1"",""day2"",""day3"",""day4"",""day5"",""day6"",""day7"",""day8"",""day9"",""day10"",""day11"",""day12"",""day13"",""day14"",""day15"",""day16"",""day17"",""total17"",""csm1"",""csm2"",""pir"\n"740abc"","""","""","""","""",""TOPPS"",""TOPPS"",""TOPPSPCS"",""7"",""19"","""",""7.563553799999999"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"","""","""",""OTHERS"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"\n"814abc"","""","""","""","""",""TRAC"",""OTHERS"",""TRAC"",""7"",""19"","""","""",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"","""","""",""OTHERS"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"\n"] |
| 4 | [""Number"",""avg_ch"",""avg_port"",""ctn"",""acc"",""car"",""net"",""car_name"",""req_w"",""req_h"",""ooids"",""last"",""ivrInt"",""ivrFai"",""careInt"",""careFai"",""retlInt"",""retlFai"",""piTE"",""piTS"",""pasC"",""ss_i"",""ss_c"",""acc_cat"",""total1"",""total2"",""total3"",""total4"",""total5"",""total6"",""total7"",""total8"",""total9"",""total10"",""total11"",""total12"",""total13"",""total14"",""total15"",""total16"",""day1"",""day2"",""day3"",""day4"",""day5"",""day6"",""day7"",""day8"",""day9"",""day10"",""day11"",""day12"",""day13"",""day14"",""day15"",""day16"",""day17"",""total17"",""csm1"",""csm2"",""pir"\n"205abc"","""","""","""","""",""ZZZZ-VERI"",""VERI"",""TRAC"",""7"",""19"","""",""278.06139585"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""SMART"",""1"",""OTHERS"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"\n"318abc"","""","""","""","""",""TRAC"",""OTHERS"",""TRAC"",""7"",""19"","""","""",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"","""","""",""OTHERS"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"\n"] |
| 5 | [""Number"",""avg_ch"",""avg_port"",""ctn"",""acc"",""car"",""net"",""car_name"",""req_w"",""req_h"",""ooids"",""last"",""ivrInt"",""ivrFai"",""careInt"",""careFai"",""retlInt"",""retlFai"",""piTE"",""piTS"",""pasC"",""ss_i"",""ss_c"",""acc_cat"",""total1"",""total2"",""total3"",""total4"",""total5"",""total6"",""total7"",""total8"",""total9"",""total10"",""total11"",""total12"",""total13"",""total14"",""total15"",""total16"",""day1"",""day2"",""day3"",""day4"",""day5"",""day6"",""day7"",""day8"",""day9"",""day10"",""day11"",""day12"",""day13"",""day14"",""day15"",""day16"",""day17"",""total17"",""csm1"",""csm2"",""pir"\n"651abc"","""","""","""","""",""ZZZZ-TM"",""TM"",""RES"",""7"",""20"","""","""",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""MOBP/FEATURE PHONE"",""1"",""OTHERS"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"\n"701abc"","""","""","""","""",""OTHERS"",""OTHERS"",""CONS"",""7"",""20"","""","""",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"","""","""",""OTHERS"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"",""0"\n"] |

**Code:**

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

output_df = (
    # Step 1
    df.withColumn("features",F.concat_ws("|","features"))
    # Step 2
      .withColumn("features",F.split("features","\n"))
    # Step 3
      .withColumn("headers",F.col("features")[0])
    # Step 4
      .select(
          F.col("id"),
          F.posexplode("features"),
          F.col("headers")
      )
    # Step 5
      .where(
          (F.col("headers") != F.col("col")) & 
          (F.length(F.col("col"))>0)
       )
    # Step 6
       .withColumnRenamed("pos","row_num")
    # Step 7
       .select(
           F.col("id"),
           F.col("row_num"),
           F.posexplode(F.split("col","\|")),
           F.split("headers","\|").alias("header")
       )
    # Step 8
       .withColumn("header",F.col("header")[F.col("pos")])
    # Step 9
       .withColumn("header",F.regexp_replace("header",'"',""))
       .withColumn("col",F.regexp_replace("col",'"',""))
    # Step 10
       .where(F.col("header").isin(["Number","car","car_name"]))
    # Step 11 
       .groupBy("id","row_num")
    # Step 12
       .pivot("header")
       .agg(
           F.max(F.col("col"))
       )
       .orderBy("id","row_num") # ordering is optional here. Included for answer presentation
)

output_df.show(truncate=False)
```

**Output with filter "Number","car","car_name":**

```
+---+-------+------+---------+--------+
|id |row_num|Number|car      |car_name|
+---+-------+------+---------+--------+
|1  |1      |608abc|ZZZZ-TM  |RES     |
|1  |2      |814abc|TRAC     |TRAC    |
|2  |1      |608abc|ZZZZ-TM  |RES     |
|2  |2      |814abc|TRAC     |TRAC    |
|3  |1      |740abc|TOPPS    |TOPPSPCS|
|3  |2      |814abc|TRAC     |TRAC    |
|4  |1      |205abc|ZZZZ-VERI|TRAC    |
|4  |2      |318abc|TRAC     |TRAC    |
|5  |1      |651abc|ZZZZ-TM  |RES     |
|5  |2      |701abc|OTHERS   |CONS    |
+---+-------+------+---------+--------+
```

**Output without filter:**

```
+---+-------+------+---+-------+------+--------+---------+--------+-------+-------+----+----+---+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+------+------+------------------+------+-----+----+----+----+---+-----+-----+-------+-------+----+------------------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|id |row_num|Number|acc|acc_cat|avg_ch|avg_port|car      |car_name|careFai|careInt|csm1|csm2|ctn|day1|day10|day11|day12|day13|day14|day15|day16|day17|day2|day3|day4|day5|day6|day7|day8|day9|ivrFai|ivrInt|last              |net   |ooids|pasC|piTE|piTS|pir|req_h|req_w|retlFai|retlInt|ss_c|ss_i              |total1|total10|total11|total12|total13|total14|total15|total16|total17|total2|total3|total4|total5|total6|total7|total8|total9|
+---+-------+------+---+-------+------+--------+---------+--------+-------+-------+----+----+---+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+------+------+------------------+------+-----+----+----+----+---+-----+-----+-------+-------+----+------------------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|1  |1      |608abc|   |OTHERS |      |        |ZZZZ-TM  |RES     |0      |0      |0   |0   |   |0   |0    |0    |0    |0    |0    |0    |0    |0    |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0     |0     |2431.3522631166666|TM    |     |0   |0   |0   |0  |20   |7    |0      |0      |    |                  |0     |0      |0      |0      |0      |0      |0      |0      |0      |0     |0     |0     |0     |0     |0     |0     |0     |
|1  |2      |814abc|   |OTHERS |      |        |TRAC     |TRAC    |0      |0      |0   |0   |   |0   |0    |0    |0    |0    |0    |0    |0    |0    |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0     |0     |                  |OTHERS|     |0   |0   |0   |0  |20   |7    |0      |0      |    |                  |0     |0      |0      |0      |0      |0      |0      |0      |0      |0     |0     |0     |0     |0     |0     |0     |0     |
|2  |1      |608abc|   |OTHERS |      |        |ZZZZ-TM  |RES     |0      |0      |0   |0   |   |0   |0    |0    |0    |0    |0    |0    |0    |0    |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0     |0     |2431.3514778000003|TM    |     |0   |0   |0   |0  |20   |7    |0      |0      |    |                  |0     |0      |0      |0      |0      |0      |0      |0      |0      |0     |0     |0     |0     |0     |0     |0     |0     |
|2  |2      |814abc|   |OTHERS |      |        |TRAC     |TRAC    |0      |0      |0   |0   |   |0   |0    |0    |0    |0    |0    |0    |0    |0    |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0     |0     |                  |OTHERS|     |0   |0   |0   |0  |20   |7    |0      |0      |    |                  |0     |0      |0      |0      |0      |0      |0      |0      |0      |0     |0     |0     |0     |0     |0     |0     |0     |
|3  |1      |740abc|   |OTHERS |      |        |TOPPS    |TOPPSPCS|0      |0      |0   |0   |   |0   |0    |0    |0    |0    |0    |0    |0    |0    |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0     |0     |7.563553799999999 |TOPPS |     |0   |0   |0   |0  |19   |7    |0      |0      |    |                  |0     |0      |0      |0      |0      |0      |0      |0      |0      |0     |0     |0     |0     |0     |0     |0     |0     |
|3  |2      |814abc|   |OTHERS |      |        |TRAC     |TRAC    |0      |0      |0   |0   |   |0   |0    |0    |0    |0    |0    |0    |0    |0    |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0     |0     |                  |OTHERS|     |0   |0   |0   |0  |19   |7    |0      |0      |    |                  |0     |0      |0      |0      |0      |0      |0      |0      |0      |0     |0     |0     |0     |0     |0     |0     |0     |
|4  |1      |205abc|   |OTHERS |      |        |ZZZZ-VERI|TRAC    |0      |0      |0   |0   |   |0   |0    |0    |0    |0    |0    |0    |0    |0    |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0     |0     |278.06139585      |VERI  |     |0   |0   |0   |0  |19   |7    |0      |0      |1   |SMART             |0     |0      |0      |0      |0      |0      |0      |0      |0      |0     |0     |0     |0     |0     |0     |0     |0     |
|4  |2      |318abc|   |OTHERS |      |        |TRAC     |TRAC    |0      |0      |0   |0   |   |0   |0    |0    |0    |0    |0    |0    |0    |0    |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0     |0     |                  |OTHERS|     |0   |0   |0   |0  |19   |7    |0      |0      |    |                  |0     |0      |0      |0      |0      |0      |0      |0      |0      |0     |0     |0     |0     |0     |0     |0     |0     |
|5  |1      |651abc|   |OTHERS |      |        |ZZZZ-TM  |RES     |0      |0      |0   |0   |   |0   |0    |0    |0    |0    |0    |0    |0    |0    |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0     |0     |                  |TM    |     |0   |0   |0   |0  |20   |7    |0      |0      |1   |MOBP/FEATURE PHONE|0     |0      |0      |0      |0      |0      |0      |0      |0      |0     |0     |0     |0     |0     |0     |0     |0     |
|5  |2      |701abc|   |OTHERS |      |        |OTHERS   |CONS    |0      |0      |0   |0   |   |0   |0    |0    |0    |0    |0    |0    |0    |0    |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0     |0     |                  |OTHERS|     |0   |0   |0   |0  |20   |7    |0      |0      |    |                  |0     |0      |0      |0      |0      |0      |0      |0      |0      |0     |0     |0     |0     |0     |0     |0     |0     |
+---+-------+------+---+-------+------+--------+---------+--------+-------+-------+----+----+---+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+------+------+------------------+------+-----+----+----+----+---+-----+-----+-------+-------+----+------------------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

Let me know if this works for you.